# Multiple testcase in a sequence in GO

Tags: go

Although Go language allows to run multiple test files in a sequence by using the command $go test packagename ,

is there a way to control this sequence using a textfile.

Like for eg: **textfile** should just contain the names of all the testcase files to be run in a sequence so that the user just modify this textfile to run the desirable testcases

like $go test textfile.txt
Is there a way of customizing in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `go test` command allows you to specify test functions to run using `go test -test.run <regex>`. You could, for example, write a little bash script or alias:

```
FILE=$1 # first argument
cat $FILE | while read regex; do # read file one line at a time
    go test -test.run "$regex"
done
```

and then you could do `./myscript.sh testFuncs.txt`, for example.